# submit form with two different Api with condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem how submit using 2 different Api.
when first Api returns success then go to second Api.
It success for first Api but second Api failed since the data is getting undefined.

this is my code

```
public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable <any> {
  return this.http.post('api/createorganisation').pipe(tap( // Log the result or error
    data => {
      if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.') {
        return this.http.post('api/createuser');
      }
    }
  ));
}
```

Hope you all can help
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pipe different `HttpClient` requests like you are doing, you should consider using the pipe operator `switchMap`. Moreover, I'm not sure your `if` statement is required since you are already in the success callback of your `Observable`.

You may use something like this :

```
public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('api/createorganisation')
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.http.post('api/createuser'))
    );
}
```

When subscribing on this, you will trigger both queries on after the other and get the result returned by the second query.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `switchMap()` operator if you have two API calls:

```
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any>{    
    return this.http.post('api/createorganisation')
        .pipe( 
             switchMap(organis => {
                 return this.http.post('api/createuser');
             })             
         );
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To see whether API is returned data, you can log it:

```
public signupform(userData: SignupRequest): Observable<any>{    
    return this.http.post('api/createorganisation')
    .pipe( 
       switchMap(organis => {
         console.log('organis: ', organis.json()); // to see data of api/createorganisation
         return this.http.post('api/createuser');
       })             
    );
}
```

Comment: how to checking if data in `api/createorganisation` already exist